# default-locale not working on production enviroment in Tomcat/JSF

Tags: jsf, tomcat, internationalization, faces-config

Here's the `application` tags of my `faces-config.xml` file:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>i18n.conteudo</base-name>
        <var>i18n</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

Inside the i18n folder I have two files:

1. `conteudo.properties`
2. `conteudo_en_US.properties`

Since the default locale is pt_BR, I didn't create a `conteudo_pt_BR.properties`. In a development environment it all works perfectly.

But once I publish it on my production environment, even if the user is using a pt_BR browser and the application is set to work with pt_BR locale, the language is set to en_US. But, if I create a `conteudo_pt_BR.properties` in the production environment resources folder the portuguese language applies as default.

Does someone have any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Which JDK/JRE version are you using in dev and which is being used in prod?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_45",

Comment: I forgot to tell you... 1.7.0_25 is my dev version and 1.7.0_45 is the prod version.

Comment: Can you reproduce the prod problem if you use the same version at dev?

Comment: Sure, I can try that. But my guess is that my dev machine is a Windows set to pt_BR locale, and the prod server is in United States. Anyways, I thought that JSF should considerate `conteudo.properties` as the default, right?

Comment: Oh, would also be possible that your webapp is somehow preferring `Locale.getDefault()` over client specified one. Are you using `<f:view locale>`?

Comment: I'm using, but with my own method in a Session Scoped bean that returns the `Locale` based on the requested URL (.com returns en_US and .com.br returns pt_BR): `<f:view locale="#{InternacionalizacaoBean.identificarIdioma()}"></f:view>`